# How to install Visual Studio Code on armhf

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know Microsoft only published amd64 version, But because of being open source I'm thinking someone made an **working** armhf build.
I tried [this](https://code.headmelted.com/#linux-install-scripts) but [It doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1256737)

Comment: There are builds out there, eg https://code.headmelted.com though I can't speak to how good they are, or if they should even be trusted.

Comment: @Oli I installed that, but it doesn't work

Comment: Then [edit] your question to include what you've tried and what happened when it didn't work.

Comment: @Oli Edited and added

Comment: Did you try launching that through the terminal? It should give information about why it's falling which may help fix it.

Comment: @l3l_aze Unfortunately, Electron apps don't log in the terminal

Comment: Oh, duh -- I'm sorry. The NPM installation method worked for me on an armv7l after some trial and error (needs make, libatomic1, python, and possibly python3, which aren't listed as dependencies). Have you tried that yet?

Comment: @l3l_aze I didn't do that, where's the instructions?

Comment: I'm sorry! Apparently I ended up using a different project, lol. [cdr/code-server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server) from GitHub. Using UserLAnd on an armv7l running Ubuntu 18.04, but it should also work on Termux I imagine. I'll work through the installation again on a fresh install and post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code now supports arm devices officially:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_50#_linux-arm-builds

If It still doesn't work, you can try web version:

https://vscode.dev

Answer (score 1):

The following script installs and runs [github.com/cdr/code-server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server) to run VSCode through the browser. Tested through UserLAnd on Android 8.1.0 running Ubuntu 18.04 on an armv7l processor. The project recommends installing it this way for processors that don't have a pre-built binary.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Dependencies for install script, building project.
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y curl build-essential pkg-config libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev libsecret-1-dev libatomic1 python

# Install nvm to install node
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"; [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"; [ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"

# Currently installs node v12.18.0; code-server requires v12+.
nvm install lts/*
npm i -g npm

# Finally, install code-server
npm i -g code-server

# Once it eventually builds, start it running on 127.0.0.1:8080 without password authentication.
code-server --auth none
```

There are some caveats mentioned in [the code-server FAQ](https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md) that would be worth reading, like "Differences compared to VSCode?" and "How do I make my keyboard shortcuts work?".